# How to compare longitude and latitude to check the source and destination are in the same country or not using google place api

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm trying to add direction on map by using google api,I have followed this link  for displaying route on maps [Drawing a route in MapKit in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834523/drawing-a-route-in-mapkit-in-iphone-sdk)

it is working fine , now the problem is when i search for source and destionation in different countries app is going to crash saying  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

- To use Apple's CLPlacemark and CLGeoCoder as this answer [Get current city and country from CLGeocoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576289/get-current-city-and-country-from-clgeocoder)
- To use the Google Geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1

Comment: Thaks for your reply but I want to display any alert if user selectes different countries as source and destinations ,so what should i do to compare

Comment: Check if the source and destination have the same country code or name that will insure that both points are in the same country. Therefore you can route else alert the user.

Comment: You can benefit from this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576289/get-current-city-and-country-from-clgeocoder