# CLGeocoder: US state Names are coming as a short codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, clgeocoder

I am developing app in iOS 8.0.

By below link, I am assigning the location object,
[How can I get current location from user in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

My aim is to find out  City, State and Country name, By current location.
Using answer of this link, I am getting the place mark objects used in Apple's Geocoder.
[Get current city and country from CLGeocoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576289/get-current-city-and-country-from-clgeocoder)

I am getting everything alright, just

**When I am getting the state name for Country United States.
It gives me shortcodes, rather than giving me full state names.**

e.g. For `Alaska` it gives me `AK`
     For `Alabama` it gives me  `AL`

Like this is my log,

```
 North Kingstown, RI, United States
```

**I want full state names, because I want to use full state name in my project.**

**I am getting state name by this code,**

```
 NSString *stateName=myPlacemark.administrativeArea;
```

Comment: Now I am using Google API for getting the city name, below is a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160503/facing-difficulty-in-parsing-google-location-response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift 5 enum with USA states list + ISO codes:

https://gist.github.com/SergLam/a252dd01324b5e2c04ecbe79cbb6b8fb

```
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_and_territory_abbreviations
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2

// NOTE: - Last two symbols from ISO 3166-2 state code
enum USAState: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    case alabama = 1
    case alaska = 2
    case arizona = 3
    case arkansas = 4
    case california = 5
    case colorado = 6
    case connecticut = 7
    case delaware = 8
    case districtOfColumbia = 9
    case florida = 10
    case georgia = 11
    case hawaii = 12
    case idaho = 13
    case illinois = 14
    case indiana = 15
    case iowa = 16
    case kansas = 17
    case kentucky = 18
    case louisiana = 19
    case maine = 20
    case maryland = 21
    case massachusetts = 22
    case michigan = 23
    case minnesota = 24
    case mississippi = 25
    case missouri = 26
    case montana = 27
    case nebraska = 28
    case nevada = 29
    case newHampshire = 30
    case newJersey = 31
    case newMexico = 32
    case newYork = 33
    case northCarolina = 34
    case northDakota = 35
    case ohio = 36
    case oklahoma = 37
    case oregon = 38
    case pennsylvania = 39
    case rhodeIsland = 40
    case southCarolina = 41
    case southDakota = 42
    case tennessee = 43
    case texas = 44
    case utah = 45
    case vermont = 46
    case virginia = 47
    case washington = 48
    case westVirginia = 49
    case wisconsin = 50
    case wyoming = 51
    
    var displayName: String {
        switch self {
        case .alabama:
            return "Alabama"
        case .alaska:
            return "Alaska"
        case .arizona:
            return "Arizona"
        case .arkansas:
            return "Arkansas"
        case .california:
            return "California"
        case .colorado:
            return "Colorado"
        case .connecticut:
            return "Connecticut"
        case .delaware:
            return "Delaware"
        case .districtOfColumbia:
            return "District of Columbia"
        case .florida:
            return "Florida"
        case .georgia:
            return "Georgia"
        case .hawaii:
            return "Hawaii"
        case .idaho:
            return "Idaho"
        case .illinois:
            return "Illinois"
        case .indiana:
            return "Indiana"
        case .iowa:
            return "Iowa"
        case .kansas:
            return "Kansas"
        case .kentucky:
            return "Kentucky"
        case .louisiana:
            return "Louisiana"
        case .maine:
            return "Maine"
        case .maryland:
            return "Maryland"
        case .massachusetts:
            return "Massachusetts"
        case .michigan:
            return "Michigan"
        case .minnesota:
            return "Minnesota"
        case .mississippi:
            return "Mississippi"
        case .missouri:
            return "Missouri"
        case .montana:
            return "Montana"
        case .nebraska:
            return "Nebraska"
        case .nevada:
            return "Nevada"
        case .newHampshire:
            return "New Hampshire"
        case .newJersey:
            return "New Jersey"
        case .newMexico:
            return "New Mexico"
        case .newYork:
            return "New York"
        case .northCarolina:
            return "North Carolina"
        case .northDakota:
            return "North Dakota"
        case .ohio:
            return "Ohio"
        case .oklahoma:
            return "Oklahoma"
        case .oregon:
            return "Oregon"
        case .pennsylvania:
            return "Pennsylvania"
        case .rhodeIsland:
            return "Rhode Island"
        case .southCarolina:
            return "South Carolina"
        case .southDakota:
            return "South Dakota"
        case .tennessee:
            return "Tennessee"
        case .texas:
            return "Texas"
        case .utah:
            return "Utah"
        case .vermont:
            return "Vermont"
        case .virginia:
            return "Virginia"
        case .washington:
            return "Washington"
        case .westVirginia:
            return "West Virginia"
        case .wisconsin:
            return "Wisconsin"
        case .wyoming:
            return "Wyoming"
        }
    }
    
    var stateCode: String {
        switch self {
        case .alabama:
            return "AL"
        case .alaska:
            return "AK"
        case .arizona:
            return "AZ"
        case .arkansas:
            return "AR"
        case .california:
            return "CA"
        case .colorado:
            return "CO"
        case .connecticut:
            return "CT"
        case .delaware:
            return "DE"
        case .districtOfColumbia:
            return "DC"
        case .florida:
            return "FL"
        case .georgia:
            return "GA"
        case .hawaii:
            return "HI"
        case .idaho:
            return "ID"
        case .illinois:
            return "IL"
        case .indiana:
            return "IN"
        case .iowa:
            return "IA"
        case .kansas:
            return "KS"
        case .kentucky:
            return "KY"
        case .louisiana:
            return "LA"
        case .maine:
            return "ME"
        case .maryland:
            return "MD"
        case .massachusetts:
            return "MA"
        case .michigan:
            return "MI"
        case .minnesota:
            return "MN"
        case .mississippi:
            return "MS"
        case .missouri:
            return "MO"
        case .montana:
            return "MT"
        case .nebraska:
            return "NE"
        case .nevada:
            return "NV"
        case .newHampshire:
            return "NH"
        case .newJersey:
            return "NJ"
        case .newMexico:
            return "NM"
        case .newYork:
            return "NY"
        case .northCarolina:
            return "NC"
        case .northDakota:
            return "ND"
        case .ohio:
            return "OH"
        case .oklahoma:
            return "OK"
        case .oregon:
            return "OR"
        case .pennsylvania:
            return "PA"
        case .rhodeIsland:
            return "RI"
        case .southCarolina:
            return "SC"
        case .southDakota:
            return "SD"
        case .tennessee:
            return "TN"
        case .texas:
            return "TX"
        case .utah:
            return "UT"
        case .vermont:
            return "VT"
        case .virginia:
            return "VA"
        case .washington:
            return "WA"
        case .westVirginia:
            return "WV"
        case .wisconsin:
            return "WI"
        case .wyoming:
            return "WY"
        }
    }
    
    var isoStateCode: String {
        switch self {
        default:
            return "USA-\(self.stateCode)"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is Swift 3 version of @Arpit B Parekh answer:

```
let stateCodes = ["AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","DC","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV","NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY"]
let fullStateNames = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","District of Columbia","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]

func shortStateName(_ state:String) -> String {
    let lowercaseNames = fullStateNames.map { $0.lowercased() }
    let dic = NSDictionary(objects: stateCodes, forKeys: lowercaseNames as [NSCopying])
    return dic.object(forKey:state.lowercased()) as? String ?? state}

func longStateName(_ stateCode:String) -> String {
    let dic = NSDictionary(objects: fullStateNames, forKeys:stateCodes as [NSCopying])
    return dic.object(forKey:stateCode) as? String ?? stateCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As, I am only using Apple's GeoCoder. It is giving me only short codes of States of USA. e.g. CA for California.

I have used google but it is quite difficult to parse.
The solution came from Wikipedia.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States

I have prepared below source to use the Full Name's from short codes.

```
NSArray *arrayShortCodes=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"AL",@"AK",@"AZ",@"AR",@"CA",@"CO",@"CT",@"DE",@"DC",@"FL",@"GA",@"HI",@"ID",@"IL",@"IN",@"IA",@"KS",@"KY",@"LA",@"ME",@"MD",@"MA",@"MI",@"MN",@"MS",@"MO",@"MT",@"NE",@"NV",@"NH",@"NJ",@"NM",@"NY",@"NC",@"ND",@"OH",@"OK",@"OR",@"PA",@"RI",@"SC",@"SD",@"TN",@"TX",@"UT",@"VT",@"VA",@"WA",@"WV",@"WI",@"WY",nil];
    NSArray *arrayFullNames=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alabama",@"Alaska",@"Arizona",@"Arkansas",@"California",@"Colorado",@"Connecticut",@"Delaware",@"District of Columbia",@"Florida",@"Georgia",@"Hawaii",@"Idaho",@"Illinois",@"Indiana",@"Iowa",@"Kansas",@"Kentucky",@"Louisiana",@"Maine",@"Maryland",@"Massachusetts",@"Michigan",@"Minnesota",@"Mississippi",@"Missouri",@"Montana",@"Nebraska",@"Nevada",@"New Hampshire",@"New Jersey",@"New Mexico",@"New York",@"North Carolina",@"North Dakota",@"Ohio",@"Oklahoma",@"Oregon",@"Pennsylvania",@"Rhode Island",@"South Carolina",@"South Dakota",@"Tennessee",@"Texas",@"Utah",@"Vermont",@"Virginia",@"Washington",@"West Virginia",@"Wisconsin",@"Wyoming", nil];

     dictionaryStateNames =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:arrayFullNames forKeys:arrayShortCodes];
```

Now, we can easily access the fullname from short codes, using the valueForKey method of NSDictionary.